# looking for a Webservice which can provide local store contact information and websites

Tags: search

Guy,

I am in need for a functionality which can take Zipcode as an input and find all the departmental stores in that area and grabs their contact information from the web. This is sort of like a webcrowler but I dont want to make it that complicated. Any ideas of how I can go on doing this ?

Is there any web service out there which can provide me this like yellow pages or something. Google API and Mappoint api wont be effective.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [google maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) and [local search](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Get_Local_Search_Results_With_Google_Maps_and_Ajax_APIs).

Answer (score 0):

Try using store locator in google maps API website..